# How to change Unity Project Settings with script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to make a game, where player can change gravity, so everything is falling torwards wall, or ceiling, or etc. I found that easiest way to do this is by changing Gravity settings in Project Settings > Physics 2D > Gravity. I had really good time playing with gravity in this window, but after a research I didn't find a way to change Gravity settings in C# Script. Is there a way to do this, or should I create my own Gravity script in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Physics2D.gravity`

Here is the Link to Unity docs for details
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-gravity.html